# Fody looks for intermediate files in the wrong directory

Tags: c#, msbuild, fody

To be able to publish a single .exe I've added [Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura)/Fody package to my C# project. I've used this package before but now I get the following error message:

> MSBUILD : error : Fody: AssemblyPath
>   "C:\Projects\X\MSBuild\obj\x86\Debug\X.exe" does not exists. If you
>   have not done a build you can ignore this error. 
>                Finished Fody 4ms.

The strange thing is, is that intermediary X.exe is correctly build here:

> C:\Projects\X\src\X\obj\x86\Debug\X.exe

The project I'm working on is fairly large. So we use a couple of MSBuild props files to put everything in the corect output directories. Both building from the command line with MSBuild and building from within Visual Studio works correctly. So I assume our props files are correct. Why is Fody looking in such a weird location for the intermediaries?

which MSBuild variable that Fody might use controls this Intermediary path?

Comment: Folder or file permissions?

Comment: I don't think thats it. MSBuild has access to all these files and folders (it created them) and Fody is just a component executed by MSBuild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/Fody/Fody/blob/25b7f8bfc8b94a0546a4eda7ae12905c170baaa8/Fody/AssemblyPathValidator.cs) that throws the exception, I see a very simple File.Exists check. It all stems from ProjectDirectory (in a WeavingTask) and you can check the places where the value is used [here](https://github.com/Fody/Fody/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ProjectDirectory&type=Code).

Since I have not used Fody, I can't tell you more than this. I would pay extra attention to the configuration files, since I don't see the ProjectDirectory being constructed anywhere, just injected from somewhere.

Comment: Thank you! It didn't occur to me to look at the source code. Somehow Fody was using a really weird obj directory. I fixed this by changing our build script to force the obj directory to something sane.